# Is there a cost or quota in api usage of Youtube Android Player Api?

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I didn't find information for this specific question in Youtube Api documentation. Also I found two questions related to this doubt but until now there is not an answer. If someone used this funtionality of the Youtube Api and knows if it has a cost or it has a quota please give an answer.

Comment: all api calls have quota. No matter what platform you are calling them on.

Comment: @Tempus playing video doesn't use any quotas. Quotas are for retrieving video information. So you can use Android API for video playback without any limitations

Comment: @user924 Just playing the videos will not incur a quota cost. But any call to the api no matter from what platform will. Directly making a link to a video, playlist or a channel will not cost anything. Doing a request for anything with the api will. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

Comment: @Tempus it's what I'm talking about. But here we are interested in the next API https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/ Some people think that if they use it for video playback with their own ids then it has some limitations.

Comment: @user924 that is just the same as the normal HTML version. Just dedicated for android. It is a control system. A base to setup on. So no quota will be used. It is basically a player script. I admit that my original comment might be seen out of context. But he/she did ask about "quotas" which are api call related.

Comment: @user924 Do you still believe there's no quota? I personally think playing videos shouldn't require and consume anything, but as for `YouTubeThumbnailView`, I'm not sure about it. Have you used `YouTubeThumbnailView` before?

Comment: @Jenix well I'm talking only about YouTube Player View

Comment: @user924 Oh, I see.

Comment: @user924 By the way, have you tried with OAuth 2.0, too? Accessing private videos using OAuth 2.0 won't consume any quota either?